# List Charts HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, treeview, orgchart

I want to create a organization tree in the following manner.

[image]

I am unable to generate the tree as shown in the figure.

Kindly need help in generating the tree as shown in the figure as i have multiple levels where some data has to be shown as an extension like Level21.

Below is the code i'm using to generate the tree.

```css
/*Now the CSS*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*Time for some hover effects*/


/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}


/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}


/*Thats all. I hope you enjoyed it.
Thanks :)*/
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li class="level11">
      <a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <ul class="level2">
        <li class="level21">
          <a href="#">Level 21</a>
        </li>
        <li class="level22">
          <a href="#">Level 22</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You seem to be generating a tree already, do you mean positioning it like your screenshot?

Comment: @CassidyWilliams yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done few tweaks to your code. This will help you get started.

My additions:

```
li.levelSide::before {
  height: 0px;
  border: none;
}

li.levelSide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  padding-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```css
/*Now the CSS*/

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.tree ul {
  padding-top: 20px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.tree li {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px 5px 0 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*We will use ::before and ::after to draw the connectors*/

.tree li::before,
.tree li::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50%;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li::after {
  right: auto;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
}


/*We need to remove left-right connectors from elements without 
any siblings*/

.tree li:only-child::after,
.tree li:only-child::before {
  display: none;
}


/*Remove space from the top of single children*/

.tree li:only-child {
  padding-top: 0;
}


/*Remove left connector from first child and 
right connector from last child*/

.tree li:first-child::before,
.tree li:last-child::after {
  border: 0 none;
}


/*Adding back the vertical connector to the last nodes*/

.tree li:last-child::before {
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 0 5px 0 0;
}

.tree li:first-child::after {
  border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/*Time to add downward connectors from parents*/

.tree ul ul::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 0;
  height: 20px;
}

.tree li a {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666;
  font-family: arial, verdana, tahoma;
  font-size: 11px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s;
}


/*Time for some hover effects*/


/*We will apply the hover effect the the lineage of the element also*/

.tree li a:hover,
.tree li a:hover+ul li a {
  background: #c8e4f8;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #94a0b4;
}


/*Connector styles on hover*/

.tree li a:hover+ul li::after,
.tree li a:hover+ul li::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul::before,
.tree li a:hover+ul ul::before {
  border-color: #94a0b4;
}


/*Thats all. I hope you enjoyed it.
Thanks :)*/

li.levelSide::before {
  height: 0px;
  border: none;
}

li.levelSide {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100%;
  padding-top: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li class="level11">
      <a href="#">Level 1</a>
      <ul class="level2">
        <li class="level21">
          <a href="#">Level 21</a>
          <ul class="level2">
            <li class="level31">
              <a href="#">Level 31</a>
            </li>
            <li class="levelSide">
              <a href="#">Side Level</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </li>

        <li class="levelSide">
          <a href="#">Side Level</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried what you've said and the tree looks like in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Mamu/8pd5b0tp/2/ but i want the sidelevel to be in between of department and sections

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to add a class to the `<ul>` elements (like "side") that:

1. Lengthens the downward connectors (probably `height: 40px`)
2. Positions the first child to be directly below the parent
3. Positions the second child to be to the right of the parent
4. Removes the existing child connectors
5. Adds a side connector to the second child.

Comment: if you can provide and example it would be much beneficial based on which i can convert it to what my client needs.

Comment: @MM0959 writing all of it is a fairly large amount of CSS for one answer, what specific example are you looking for?  How to position properly?

Comment: i tried the example (https://jsfiddle.net/Mamu/8pd5b0tp/2/) as one of the user has said. If i have more than 2 items in the same level i want the side level to be positioned between level1 and level2.